# tableau sheet or dashboard turn grey and refresh is required for every actions made

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dashboard

I have experiencing some issue in the tableau worksheet or dashboard turn inactive as follow:

1. when I drag and drop a dimension or measure value on the sheet.
2. when I click the filter to change the input on the sheet.
3. when I click the filter to change the input on the dashboard comprises a few sheet.
   Below is the screen shot of the sheet before I change the filter.

[image]

I will now change the filter [change the team in the filter] and  it turns to be inactive  and the filter is not activating as follow:

[image]

I need to go to data and refresh to get the value base on the filter and here is the view after refresh.

[image]

Can Anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: Check if Dashboard (menu bar at the top) -> Auto Update is ticked?

Comment: @gherka Hi, Thanks for the reply. I did not tick it. I will tick and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your dashboard isn't automatically refreshing. Make sure you have Auto Update ticked in the dashboard menu:

[image]

Another potential cause could be that auto updates are paused. You can re-enabled them by clicking on this icon:

[image]